# WPF Designer Extensibility for TextBox

Tags: wpf, vs-extensibility

I want to modify the property table in VS 2010 that is associated with silverlight textbox.
I like to add a new property to the property table of a silverlight textbox without creating a custom control.
If I want to add a property called "Default value", and I want to run custom code when the user assign it from design-time property table
Can I do that?
I am reading about WPF designer extensibility, but all what I can find are for custom controls with custom properties.
Can we do it for an existing control?

Answer (score 1):

No it is certainly not possible. You have to create a custom control thats the only way.